# Jquery Sorting divs according their texts

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I want to rearrange parent divs according to their texts. Here is my codes:

```
$('#duration').click(function() {
var  u1 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-0 div .otp-itinTripSummary #ucret').text();
var u2 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-1 div .otp-itinTripSummary #ucret').text();
var u3 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-2 div .otp-itinTripSummary #ucret').text();
var u4 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-3 div .otp-itinTripSummary #ucret').text();
var arrayUcret = [u1,u2,u3,u4];
arrayUcret.sort();
  });
```

How can I order my divs (#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-0, #planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-1, #planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-2, #planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-3) according to sorted array.

Comment: NB: You should *not* give different elements the same id (e.g. `ucret`): it is invalid in HTML and can lead to unexpected results in your JS code. Also: Please provide the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before sorting, pair each text with the `div` element it belongs to (in a sub array), and then sort the array of those pairs based on the texts. That way also the `div` element references will be sorted at the same time.

Then append those elements one after the other in the sort order you have. This will actually *move* those elements into place.

NB: I have replaced `#ucret` with `.ucret`, because HTML does not allow duplicate `id` attribute values. So change your HTML to use `class="ucret"` instead of `id="ucret"`.

```
$('#duration').click(function() {
    var u1 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-0 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u2 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-1 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u3 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-2 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u4 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-3 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    [u1, u2, u3, u4]
        // Pair the DIV element with each text
        .map( (u, i) => [u, $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-' + i)] )
        // Sort by the text part    
        .sort( (a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) )
        // Move each element relative to the previous one in the sort order
        .reduce( (a, b) => {
            a[1].after(b[1]);
            return b;
        });
});
```

```js
$('#duration').click(function() {
    var u1 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-0 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u2 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-1 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u3 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-2 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    var u4 = $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-3 div .otp-itinTripSummary .ucret').text();
    [u1, u2, u3, u4]
        // Pair the DIV element with each text
        .map( (u, i) => [u, $('#planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-' + i)] )
        // Sort by the text part    
        .sort( (a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) )
        // Move each element relative to the previous one in the sort order
        .reduce( (a, b) => {
            a[1].after(b[1]);
            return b;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="duration">Sort</button>
<div id="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-0" class="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord">
    <div>
        <div class="otp-itinTripSummary">
            <div class="ucret">hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-1" class="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord">
    <div>
        <div class="otp-itinTripSummary">
            <div class="ucret">word</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-2" class="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord">
    <div>
        <div class="otp-itinTripSummary">
            <div class="ucret">foo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord-3" class="planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord">
    <div>
        <div class="otp-itinTripSummary">
            <div class="ucret">bar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery custom sorting function.

Set a common class for all related div such as **planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord**, then:

```
$('.planner-itinWidget-itinsAccord').sort(function (el1, el2) {
    return $(el1).text() > $(el2).text();
}
```